# Accessing express.js's connect

Tags: node.js, express, connect, locomotivejs

I am using Locomotive, and am wondering whether there is a way to access the `connect` that belongs to the `express` object somehow. Right now I am loading `connect` via `require`, and had to `npm install --save connect` first to make that happen. How can I use the `connect` that belongs to Express/Locomotive. Is that a bad idea? Should I just maintain my own dependency?

Comment: You could probably get it through `require('express/node_modules/connect')`, but why do you want to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you use something like:

```
.use(express.cookieParser())
```

you are using the underlying connect methods, which have been extended by express. So, you don't need to install a separate copy of connect.